# Nginx restart silently failing

Tags: nginx

I'm having a bit of an issue with Nginx silently failing on restart on Centos6. 
If Nginx is running, `service nginx restart` will stop it, without actually restarting it. 
Yet it outputs:

```
Checking configuration of nginx:                           [  OK  ]
Stopping nginx:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting nginx:                                            [  OK  ]
```

Again, it says nginx is started successfully, yet a status check shows that it isn't. If nginx is already stopped, though, `service nginx restart` will work. Consequently a double restart will restart it.

The error.log for accompanying the output above only has:

```
2015/03/03 21:53:17 [notice] 14093#0: signal process started
```

Any thoughts as to why this is happening?

`reload` does not have this same problem. Is it swappable with restart when config changes are made?

Comment: Check config with `nginx -t`. Reload will silently ignore new config if it contains errors.

Comment: Would this have been the same, though? 
`Checking configuration of nginx:                           [  OK  ]` . I've reinstalled everything since this error, including different linux flavor, so I can't repeat the issue. So, at this point, the question is "closed" for me.

Comment: run `sudo service nginx restart`